# Shake detection mouse

Tags: c#, winforms

My code is used to form1

```
        private int X,Y;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.X != Cursor.Position.X ||
            this.Y != Cursor.Position.Y)
        {
            this.Form1_Load(this, e);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = (Convert.ToInt16(this.Text)+1).ToString();
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "0";
        this.X = Cursor.Position.X;
        this.Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
    }
```

Other forms will not answer

If the form2 is open. The above code does not work.

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? By the way, don't call `Form_Load` from an event handler - only the WinForms framework should call that.

Comment: @Michael: Why shouldn't usercode call a self-written function? If you like to call the same code which you like to call in the FormLoad event called again just do it (but that wouldn't hinder someone to do a little more refactoring).

Comment: @Oliver: it's just bad practice, and will lead to misunderstandings in the future. The function of `Form_Load` is well-understood - the framework calls it (in sequence with other handlers) when the form is loaded. Messing with that is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure what exactly want to accomplish, but try to set `form2.Owner = this` (if you show form2 from from1) or form2.Owner = form1.

Answer (score 0):

This code for the screensaver :

//inForm1

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    //...

    private const int SC_SCREENSAVE = 0xF140;
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;

    //...

    public static void SetScreenSaverRunning()
    {
        SendMessage

    (GetDesktopWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0);
    }


    public void Shakedetectionmouse(EventArgs e)
    {
        //CallTimer1_Tick
       timer1_Tick(this,e);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ShowScreenSaver
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        SetScreenSaverRunning();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ShowForm2
        using (var Form2 = new Form2())
        {
            Form2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

//Inform2

```
       private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 2000;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using(var form1 = new Form1())
        {
            form1.Shakedetectionmouse(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

In any form should be used Timer Component

Is it not a way to solve this issue?

screen saver  Windows can be used?

Comment: Edit your question with these details; don't create an answer unless you're answering your question.